# Какую базу выбрать для таблица на 20 млн. строк?

Tags: база-данных

Опыта работы с большими данными нет, как и нет опыта работы с noSQL.

Данных много (20 млн. строк), все они записаны в одну таблицу, предполагается, что они не будут изменяться.

Что нужно делать с данными: строить простые выборки + иногда применять алгоритм Левенштейна для поиска похожих строк.

Данные в исходном виде лежат в виде csv файлов. Есть мысль импортировать их в sqlite и попробовать поработать с ним. Но, всё же, может мне стоит выбрать какое-то другое решение?

Comment: Вам, в целом, подойдёт что угодно, где реализовано (или реализуемо) расстояние Левенштейна. [В SQLite это, кажется, есть](http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html#editdist3). В чём суть вопроса?

Comment: я бы postgress брал

Comment: PostgreSQL действительно [умеет левенштейна](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html), я бы взял его. 20 миллионов строк не проблема практически ни для какой БД, но SQLite явно не стоит брать, если только проблема не одноразовая. Чуть позже попытаюсь написать более подробный ответ.

Comment: @Etki SQL Server [тоже умеет левенштейна](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27734606/1988244). так что ответ на вопрос на самом деле зависит от личных предпочтений отвечающего

Comment: @PashaPash оттуда и "я бы"

Comment: Проблема ещё в том, как мне экспортировать такой большой дамп? Для работы с базами пользуюсь Navicat, так он за 10 минут экспорта даже 1% не выдал. Собственно, поэтому и смотрел в сторону SQLite.
Тогда получается план такой: брать PostgreSQL, создать таблицу, расставить индексы, импортнуть данные из CSV-файлов, затем каким-то образом создать дамп и залить его на сервер. Верно?

Comment: @PendalF в постгрес можно [прямо из CSV](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: @D-side это здорово, но хотелось бы сначала на локале сделать, а потом уже на сервер загрузить дамп.

Comment: @PendalF так поставьте локальную БД :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полноценный ответ на этот вопрос скрыт за необъявленными требованиями к конкретному хранилищу, поэтому здесь будут скорее некоторые объяснения, чем советы.

Хранилища можно условно поделить на пять основных типов - реляционные, column-family, key-value, документоориентированные и графовые. Первое, что нужно сделать - это понять, какие типы не подходят под условия и сразу вылетают. В данном случае прозвучало слово "выборка", и не прозвучало ничего про сложные связи - поэтому точно можно выкинуть key-value хранилища и не обращать внимания на графовые. Остаются три типа - реляционные, column-family и документоориентированные, финальный выбор из которых зависит от структурированности данных. В случае, если данные не имеют постоянной структуры и имеют различную вложенность, но необходимо осуществлять поиск по атрибутам, то остается только вариант с документоориентированным хранилищем; в противном случае можно выбрать стандартную реляционную модель или column-family хранилище (с клиентской стороны они довольно похожи, только column-family выглядит сильно урезанной - например, в column-family обычно отсутствует понятие join), хотя никто не запретит здесь использовать что-нибудь документоориентированное.
Отдельно хочу заметить, что 20 миллионов строк - это большое число только с человеческой точки зрения; несмотря на то, что любое хранилище сожрет действительно внушительный объем дискового пространства при таком импорте, "умереть" оно не должно, такие объемы - это нормально в современных сервисах, поэтому по умолчанию можно считать, что любое хранилище способно работать с необходимыми данными. Какому-нибудь GUI будет сложно вывести всю выборку (потому что для этого будет необходимо держать в оперативной памяти все данные), но само хранилище и клиентский код должны обрабатывать записи небольшими пачками, не выжирая всю оперативку.

Насколько я понял из упоминания CSV, данные жестко структурированы, поэтому проще всего было бы взять какую-нибудь реляционную БД (column-family - отдельный зверь, в который не хотелось бы запрыгивать на ходу, и, скорее всего, реализаций алгоритма Левенштейна нет ни в одной; кроме того, cf-хранилища нацелены на распределенное хранение частей данных, в то время как здесь при любом запросе нужно будет обрабатывать все данные целиком, и это не получится сделать просто на каждом отдельном узле) и работать с ней; необходимость определять расстояние левенштейна во время запроса еще сильнее сужают круг возможных хранилищ: из известных бесплатных это только SQLite и PostgreSQL. И здесь можно либо выбрать PostgreSQL, либо разобрать задачу еще немного подробнее.

Во-первых, насколько понимаю, само задание к продукту требует не искать расстояние Левенштейна, а сравнивать некоторый ввод X со всеми присутствующими в хранилище значениями. Во-вторых, эта задача сильно бьет по самой идее индексов, которые обычно используются для ускорения поиска: индексы строятся по точным значениям, в то время как здесь точное значение для индекса вычислить невозможно, как и построить дерево для более быстрого поиска. Попытка заранее подсчитать расстояние для всех возможных вариантов скорее всего закончится вместе с дисковым пространством. Поэтому здесь, возможно, стоит обратиться к дополнительным решениям.

Самая первая оптимизация, которую можно придумать - это вынести те атрибуты, по которым может вестись поиск, в отдельные таблицы. Так или иначе хранилище будет итерировать по всем записям (теоретически, оно может итерировать по самому индекс, но я в этом сильно не уверен), поэтому просто для ускорения чтения можно дублировать необходимые вещи в отдельных таблицах. Также можно поставить условие к приложению, что префикс искомого слова (скажем, первая треть символов с округлением в меньшую сторону) всегда корректен, и искать по уменьшенной выборке. Также в том случае, если есть максимально допустимое расстояние, можно ограничить выборку по длине записей и применять сам функцию определения расстояния для значительно меньшего словаря.

Вторая оптимизация, которая будет не настолько очевидна, как третья, но про которую хотелось бы сказать чуть раньше - это построение некоторой промежуточной модели для нечеткого поиска. В том случае, если действительно необходимо искать похожие слова, а не расстояние Левенштейна, можно произвести предварительное фонетическое преобразование терминов (если, конечно, это позволяют требования к приложению). Возможно, стоит преобразовать все упоминания "терраса", "терасса" и "террасса" к "тераса", чтобы синонимизировать эти слова; в этом случае (опять же, если поставленные к приложению условия это позволяют) искать расстояние Левенштейна вообще не придется (при этом поисковый запрос надо будет прогонять через тот же фильтр перед нахождением совпадений). С этим, в частности, работает фильтр snowball в поисковом движке Elasticsearch, который, возможно, и требуется в приложении; кроме того, ES позволит искать не конкретные совпадения в заданных рамках, а *необходимое число самых близких результатов* (хотя про это стоило бы написать отдельный пост, и конкретно с расстоянием Левенштейна все будет не очень просто). NB: в официальном блоге ES [просят](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search) очень осторожно относиться к подобным запросам, т.к. по понятным причинам они действительно медленны и прожорливы. Сам по себе ElasticSearch является решением большинства поисковых проблем на свете, но для корректного использования следует понимать происходящие внутри процессы и постоянно обновлять как сами документы, так и индексы целиком, и нырнуть в него будет так же сложно, как и в column-family базы данных.

И, наконец, третья оптимизация, являющаяся самой ресурсолюбивой и требовательной, и, в то же время, самой оптимальной. Можно просто запихнуть все данные, по которым ведется поиск, в оперативку, и работать прямо на ходу. Это самый скорострельный вариант, который, впрочем, плохо шардируется (хотя и остаются предыдущие хаки с префиксом/суффиксом и длиной слова) и требует большого внимания, однако на больших объемах данных очень часто склоняются именно к нему (потому что это проще, чем поддерживать флот баз данных, а одна машина способна обрабатывать гигантские объемы запросов). В частности, существует [автомат Левенштейна](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275937/) (disclaimer: я пока не нашел времени прочитать про него), который, скорее всего, решит все проблемы. Предложенный в предыдущем варианте ElasticSearch, насколько мне известно, использует именно автомат Левенштейна, но я не могу предположить, сколько ему потребуется оперативной памяти (наверняка будет какой-то оверхед; ES можно заставить свопиться на диск, но авторы ES этого крайне не рекомендуют), и как его корректно настроить.

Подводя итог: скорее всего, PostgreSQL или аналог подойдет под задачи, но сами предполагаемые операции являются довольно ресурсоемкими, поэтому я бы рассматривал альтернативные варианты.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ!